# apt-get wants to auto delete important packages

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall

when i'm using apt-get upgrade, it shows me this, but I need those packages, how can I require those packages?

```
root@K411:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ace-voip aircrack-ng amap apache2-data arj arp-scan arping arpwatch atftpd
  attr axel baobab bed bluelog blueranger bluesnarfer bluez-hcidump braa
  btscanner ca-certificates-java cabextract cadaver castxml cdpsnarf cgpt
  chntpw cisco-auditing-tool cisco-global-exploiter cisco-ocs cisco-torch
  clang cmospwd commix cramfsswap crunch cryptcat curlftpfs cutycapt cymothoa
  darkstat dbd dc3dd dcfldd dconf-editor dconf-tools dcraw ddrescue
  default-jre default-jre-headless dmitry dns2tcp dnsenum dnsmap dnstracer
  dnswalk docutils-common docutils-doc doona dos2unix dotdotpwn driftnet
  dwarfdump empathy-common enumiax erlang-asn1 erlang-base erlang-crypto
  erlang-eunit erlang-inets erlang-mnesia erlang-os-mon erlang-public-key
  erlang-runtime-tools erlang-snmp erlang-ssl erlang-syntax-tools
  erlang-webtool erlang-xmerl espeak-data ethtool ettercap-common
  ettercap-graphical ewf-tools exe2hexbat exif exiv2 expect exploitdb
  extundelete fastjar fcrackzip fern-wifi-cracker fierce fiked file-roller
  fimap findmyhash finger firebird2.5-common firebird2.5-common-doc flac flasm
  florence fonts-cantarell fonts-lyx fonts-wine foremost fping fragroute
  fragrouter framework2 freeglut3 freetds-common ftester funkload galleta
  gccxml gconf2 gdebi-core gedit gedit-common genisoimage geoclue-2.0
  geoip-database geoip-database-extra ghost-phisher gir1.2-gmenu-3.0
  gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0
  gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.91
  gir1.2-wnck-3.0 giskismet git git-man gksu gnome-accessibility-themes
  gnome-bluetooth gnome-brave-icon-theme gnome-calculator gnome-colors-common
  gnome-dictionary gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-mime-data
  gnome-online-miners gnome-packagekit gnome-packagekit-data gnome-screenshot
  gnome-shell-extension-dashtodock gnome-shell-extension-easyscreencast
  gnome-shell-extension-proxyswitcher gnome-shell-extension-refreshwifi
  gnome-shell-extension-workspacestodock gnome-shell-extensions
  gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-theme-kali gnome-themes-standard
  gnome-tweak-tool gnustep-base-common gnustep-base-runtime gnustep-common
  gparted gpp-decrypt grabber gtk2-engines gtk2-engines-murrine
  gtk2-engines-pixbuf gucharmap guymager gvfs-fuse hackrf hamster-sidejack
  hash-identifier hashcat hashcat-utils hashdeep hashid hdparm hexinject
  hexorbase hotpatch hping3 httrack hydra hydra-gtk i2c-tools iaxflood
  ieee-data ifenslave ike-scan inetsim inguma intersect intrace inviteflood
  iodine iproute ipython irpas jad jarwrapper java-common java-wrappers
  jboss-autopwn john john-data johnny joomscan jsql kali-defaults kali-menu
  kali-root-login keepnote keimpx killerbee king-phisher kismet laudanum lbd
  ldap-utils leafpad libadns1 libafflib0v5 libaio1 libalgorithm-c3-perl
  libao-common libao4 libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap libatk-adaptor libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni
  libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libaudio2 libavahi-core7 libavdevice-ffmpeg56
  libavfilter-ffmpeg5 libb-hooks-endofscope-perl libbfio1 libbind9-90
  libbluetooth-dev libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libboost-filesystem1.58.0
  libboost-python1.58.0 libboost-system1.58.0 libboost-thread1.58.0
  libbrlapi0.6 libc-ares2 libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libcaribou-gtk-module
  libcaribou-gtk3-module libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl
  libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libclass-c3-perl libclass-c3-xs-perl
  libclass-load-perl libclass-load-xs-perl libclass-tiny-perl libcli1.9
  libconfig9 libcrypto++9v5 libct4 libcurses-perl libcurses-ui-perl libdaemon0
  libdata-optlist-perl libdate-manip-perl libdbd-mysql-perl
  libdbd-sqlite3-perl libdbi-perl libdevel-caller-perl
  libdevel-globaldestruction-perl libdevel-lexalias-perl
  libdevel-overloadinfo-perl libdevel-partialdump-perl
  libdevel-stacktrace-perl libdigest-crc-perl libdigest-md4-perl
  libdigest-md5-file-perl libdist-checkconflicts-perl libdistorm3-3 libdns100
  libdotconf0 libdumbnet1 libemu2 liberror-perl libespeak1
  libeval-closure-perl libevent-core-2.0-5 libevent-openssl-2.0-5
  libevent-pthreads-2.0-5 libewf2 libexiv2-14 libexporter-tiny-perl
  libfbclient2 libfcgi-perl libfindrtp libflorence-1.0-1 libfreefare-bin
  libfreefare0 libgail-common libgail18 libgdict-1.0-9 libgdict-common
  libgeoclue-2-0 libgeoip1 libgeos-3.5.0 libgeos-c1v5 libgfbgraph-0.2-0
  libgif4 libgksu2-0 libglade2-0 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libgnome-2-0
  libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnome2-common
  libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-extra libgnustep-base1.24
  libgssglue1 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 libgtksourceview2.0-0
  libgtksourceview2.0-common libgucharmap-2-90-7 libguytools2 libhackrf0
  libhivex-bin libhivex0 libhtml-linkextractor-perl libhtml-template-perl
  libhttp-dav-perl libhttp-parser2.1 libhttp-server-simple-perl libhttrack2
  libice-dev libilmbase6v5 libio-all-lwp-perl libio-all-perl
  libio-multiplex-perl libio-socket-socks-perl libipc-shareable-perl libisc95
  libisccc90 libisccfg90 libjansson4 libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0
  libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjpeg-progs libjpeg9 libjs-excanvas
  libjs-jquery-easing libjs-jquery-fancybox libjs-jquery-form
  libjs-jquery-mousewheel libjs-jquery-ui libjs-mochikit libjs-openlayers
  libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libjudydebian1 libladr4 liblinear3
  liblist-moreutils-perl liblog4cpp5v5 liblouis-data liblouis9 libluajit-5.1-2
  libluajit-5.1-common liblwp-protocol-socks-perl liblwres90 libmagic-dev
  libmaxminddb0 libmdb2 libmdbsql2 libmodule-implementation-perl
  libmodule-runtime-conflicts-perl libmodule-runtime-perl libmoose-perl
  libmozjs185-1.0 libmro-compat-perl libmspack0 libmysqlclient18
  libnamespace-clean-perl libnet-cidr-perl libnet-netmask-perl
  libnet-pcap-perl libnet-rawip-perl libnet-server-perl libnet-snmp-perl
  libnet-ssh2-perl libnet-telnet-perl libnet-tftp-perl libnet1
  libnetpacket-perl libnfc-bin libnfc5 libnids1.21 libnl-route-3-200
  libnumber-bytes-human-perl libonig2 libopenexr6v5 libopts25 liborbit-2-0
  libpackage-deprecationmanager-perl libpackage-stash-perl
  libpackage-stash-xs-perl libpackagekit-glib2-18 libpadwalker-perl
  libpango1.0-0 libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libparallel-forkmanager-perl
  libparams-classify-perl libparams-util-perl libparted-fs-resize0
  libpcsc-perl libpff1 libpgm-5.1-0 libphonon4 libpkcs11-helper1
  libproxychains3 libpst4 libpthread-stubs0-dev libqcustomplot1.3 libqdbm14
  libqgsttools-p1 libqscintilla2-12v5 libqscintilla2-l10n libqt4-dbus
  libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-opengl
  libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql
  libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns
  libqt5multimedia5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediawidgets5
  libqt5opengl5 libqt5scintilla2-12v5 libqt5scintilla2-l10n libqt5test5
  libqtassistantclient4 libqtcore4 libqtdbus4 libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4
  libqwt5-qt4 libradare2-0.9.9 libradare2-common libradare2-dev libregfi0
  libsctp1 libsensors4 libserf-1-1 libsigc++-2.0-0v5 libsm-dev libsmi2ldbl
  libsnmp-base libsnmp-perl libsnmp30 libsodium13 libsonic0 libspeechd2
  libspiffy-perl libssh-4 libstring-random-perl libsub-exporter-perl
  libsub-exporter-progressive-perl libsub-identify-perl libsub-install-perl
  libsub-name-perl libsvn1 libsybdb5 libtask-weaken-perl libtcl8.5
  libtelepathy-farstream3 libterm-readkey-perl libtidy-0.99-0 libtk8.5 libtre5
  libtry-tiny-perl libtsk13 libucl1 liburcu4 libuv1 libvariable-magic-perl
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwebpdemux1 libwebpmux1 libwhisker2-perl libwine
  libwireshark-data libwireshark6 libwiretap5 libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common
  libwsutil6 libwww-mechanize-perl libx11-dev libx11-doc libx86-1 libxau-dev
  libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxml-dom-perl libxml-libxml-perl
  libxml-namespacesupport-perl libxml-perl libxml-regexp-perl
  libxml-sax-base-perl libxml-sax-expat-perl libxml-sax-perl
  libxml-writer-perl libxres1 libxt-dev libyara3 libzapojit-0.0-0 libzip2
  libzmq3 lrzsz lua-lpeg lynis magicrescue magictree maskprocessor masscan mc
  mc-data mdbtools mdk3 medusa memdump menu mercurial mercurial-common
  metasploit-framework mfcuk mfoc mfterm mimikatz minicom miranda miredo
  missidentify mitmproxy mpg123 mtd-utils multiforcer multimac murrine-themes
  mysql-client-5.6 mysql-client-core-5.6 mysql-common mysql-server
  mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server-core-5.6 nasm nbtscan ncat-w32 ncrack
  ncurses-hexedit ndiff netdiscover netmask netsed netsniff-ng netwag netwox
  nfspy ngrep nikto nipper-ng nishang nmap nodejs ntp ocl-icd-libopencl1
  ollydbg onesixtyone openbsd-inetd openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless
  opensc opensc-pkcs11 openssh-server openssh-sftp-server openvpn ophcrack
  ophcrack-cli oscanner p0f p7zip p7zip-full pack packagekit packagekit-tools
  padbuster paros pasco passing-the-hash patator pcsc-tools pdf-parser pdfid
  pdgmail peepdf perl-cisco-copyconfig pev phonon phonon-backend-vlc php5-cli
  php5-common php5-json php5-mysql php5-readline pipal pixiewps plecost
  polenum postgresql powerfuzzer powersploit protos-sip prover9 proxychains
  proxystrike proxytunnel pst-utils ptunnel pwgen pwnat pyrit python-adns
  python-alembic python-anyjson python-apsw python-argcomplete python-argh
  python-backports.ssl-match-hostname python-beautifulsoup python-blinker
  python-bluez python-boltons python-bs4 python-bson python-bson-ext
  python-capstone python-certifi python-cffi-backend python-characteristic
  python-cheetah python-clamd python-click python-cluster python-colorama
  python-concurrent.futures python-configargparse python-configobj
  python-configparser python-construct python-couchdbkit python-cryptography
  python-ctypeslib python-cycler python-d2to1 python-dap
  python-darts-lib-utils-lru python-dateutil python-dbus-dev python-decorator
  python-defusedxml python-dicttoxml python-distlib python-distorm3 python-dns
  python-dnspython python-docutils python-dominate python-easygui python-ecdsa
  python-editor python-egenix-mxdatetime python-egenix-mxtools python-elixir
  python-enum34 python-esmre python-faraday python-feedparser python-flask
  python-flickrapi python-formencode python-fuse python-geoip python-geoip2
  python-geojson python-gevent python-git python-gitdb python-glade2
  python-googleapi python-greenlet python-gridfs python-gtksourceview2
  python-guess-language python-halberd python-hpack python-html2text
  python-html5lib python-http-parser python-httpretty python-icalendar
  python-idna python-imaging python-impacket python-instagram python-ipaddr
  python-ipaddress python-ipy python-itsdangerous python-jdcal python-jinja2
  python-jsonpickle python-jsonrpclib python-jwt python-levenshtein
  python-libxml2 python-libxslt1 python-lxml python-lzma python-lzo
  python-m2crypto python-magic python-mako python-markdown python-markupsafe
  python-matplotlib python-matplotlib-data python-maxminddb python-mechanize
  python-metaconfig python-mockito python-mpltoolkits.basemap
  python-mpltoolkits.basemap-data python-msgpack python-mysqldb python-nassl
  python-ndg-httpsclient python-netaddr python-netlib python-nltk python-ntlm
  python-oauth2client python-oauthlib python-olefile python-opengl
  python-openid python-openpyxl python-openssl python-pam python-paramiko
  python-passlib python-paste python-pastedeploy python-pastedeploy-tpl
  python-pastescript python-pathtools python-pcapy python-pdfminer
  python-pefile python-pexpect python-phply python-pil python-pil.imagetk
  python-ply python-prettytable python-psutil python-psycopg2
  python-ptyprocess python-py python-pyasn1 python-pyasn1-modules
  python-pyatspi python-pybloomfiltermmap python-pycryptopp python-pyexiv2
  python-pyexiv2-doc python-pygithub python-pygments python-pyinotify
  python-pylibemu python-pymongo python-pymongo-ext python-pymssql
  python-pyotp python-pyparsing python-pypdf python-pypdf2 python-pyperclip
  python-pyqtgraph python-pyregfi python-pyscard python-pysnmp4
  python-pysnmp4-apps python-pysnmp4-mibs python-pysqlite2 python-pytest
  python-pyx python-qscintilla2 python-qt4 python-qt4-gl python-qt4-phonon
  python-requests python-requests-oauthlib python-requests-toolbelt
  python-restkit python-rfidiot python-roman python-rsa python-rsvg
  python-ruamel.ordereddict python-scapy python-scgi python-scipy
  python-serial python-service-identity python-simplegeneric python-simplejson
  python-sip python-slowaes python-smmap python-smoke-zephyr python-soappy
  python-socketpool python-socks python-sqlalchemy python-sqlalchemy-ext
  python-stopit python-svn python-tblib python-tempita python-termcolor
  python-tidylib python-tornado python-tweepy python-twisted
  python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core python-twisted-web python-tz
  python-tzlocal python-uritemplate python-urllib3 python-usb python-utidylib
  python-vulndb python-watchdog python-webkit python-webunit python-werkzeug
  python-wheel python-whoosh python-wstools python-wxgtk3.0 python-wxtools
  python-wxversion python-xdot python-xlsxwriter python-yaml python-yapsy
  python-yara python-zope.interface python3-apt python3-brlapi python3-cairo
  python3-chardet python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-dbus python3-debian
  python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-louis python3-pkg-resources
  python3-pyatspi python3-requests python3-six python3-smbc python3-speechd
  python3-urllib3 python3-xdg qdbus qt-at-spi qtchooser qtcore4-l10n radare2
  rainbowcrack rake ratproxy rcconf rcracki-mt rdesktop read-edid readpst
  reaver rebind recon-ng recordmydesktop recoverjpeg redfang redsocks
  reglookup reglookup-doc regripper responder rfkill rifiuti rifiuti2
  rsmangler rsync rtpbreak rtpflood rtpinsertsound rtpmixsound
  ruby-addressable ruby-ansi ruby-atomic ruby-buftok ruby-daemons
  ruby-dataobjects ruby-dataobjects-mysql ruby-dataobjects-postgres
  ruby-dataobjects-sqlite3 ruby-diff-lcs ruby-dm-core ruby-dm-do-adapter
  ruby-dm-migrations ruby-dm-serializer ruby-dm-sqlite-adapter ruby-docile
  ruby-domain-name ruby-em-websocket ruby-equalizer ruby-erubis ruby-ethon
  ruby-eventmachine ruby-execjs ruby-faraday ruby-ffi ruby-geoip ruby-http
  ruby-http-cookie ruby-http-parser.rb ruby-httpclient ruby-json ruby-librex
  ruby-libv8 ruby-memoizable ruby-mime ruby-mime-types ruby-mini-exiftool
  ruby-mojo-magick ruby-msfrpc-client ruby-msgpack ruby-multi-json
  ruby-multipart-post ruby-naught ruby-net-http-digest-auth ruby-nokogiri
  ruby-oj ruby-parseconfig ruby-qr4r ruby-rack ruby-rack-protection
  ruby-rainbow ruby-rchardet ruby-ref ruby-rexec ruby-rqrcode
  ruby-rspec-expectations ruby-rspec-support ruby-ruby-progressbar
  ruby-rubydns ruby-simple-oauth ruby-simplecov ruby-simplecov-html
  ruby-sinatra ruby-spider ruby-sqlite3 ruby-term-ansicolor
  ruby-terminal-table ruby-therubyracer ruby-thread-safe ruby-tilt ruby-tins
  ruby-twitter ruby-typhoeus ruby-uglifier ruby-unf ruby-unf-ext ruby-yajl
  ruby-zip rwho rwhod safecopy sakis3g samba samba-dsdb-modules
  samba-vfs-modules samdump2 sbd scalpel screen scrounge-ntfs sctpscan
  sendemail sfuzz sidguesser siege siparmyknife sipcrack sipp sipvicious
  skipfish sleuthkit smali smartmontools smbmap smitools smtp-user-enum
  sniffjoke snmp snmpcheck snmpd socat sound-theme-freedesktop sparta
  spectools speech-dispatcher speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins spike spooftooph
  sqldict sqlite3 sqlitebrowser sqlmap sqlninja sqlsus sqsh squashfs-tools
  sslcaudit ssldump sslh sslscan sslsniff sslsplit sslstrip sslyze
  statsprocessor stunnel4 subversion suckless-tools sucrack
  system-config-printer-udev sysv-rc-conf t50 tcl-expect tcpdump tcpflow
  tcpick tcpreplay tcpwatch-httpproxy tdb-tools telepathy-gabble
  telepathy-logger termineter testdisk texlive-latex-base
  texlive-latex-base-doc tftp tftpd32 thc-ipv6 thc-pptp-bruter thc-ssl-dos
  theharvester thin tk8.5 tlssled tmux tnscmd10g truecrack tshark twofi
  tzdata-java u3-pwn u3-tool ua-tester udptunnel unar unicornscan uniscan
  unix-privesc-check upx-ucl urlcrazy vboot-kernel-utils vboot-utils vinetto
  vino vlan vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-samba voiphopper volafox volatility
  volatility-tools vpnc vpnc-scripts w3af w3af-console wafw00f wapiti wce
  webacoo webscarab webshells weevely wfuzz whatweb wifi-honey wifitap wifite
  windows-binaries wine wine64 winexe wireless-regdb wireshark
  wireshark-common wireshark-qt wol-e wordlists x11-apps x11proto-core-dev
  x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xbrlapi xclip xorg-sgml-doctools xprobe
  xserver-xorg-legacy xspy xsser xtightvncviewer xtrans-dev yersinia zenmap
  zerofree zim zsh zsh-common
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  bluez-obexd bundler cpp cpp-5 default-jre default-jre-headless
  evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common g++ g++-5 gcc gcc-5
  gcc-5-base gdm3 gedit gedit-common ghostscript gir1.2-mutter-3.0
  gir1.2-totem-1.0 gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data
  gnome-dictionary gnome-keyring gnome-online-miners gnome-session
  gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell
  gnome-shell-common gnome-shell-extension-workspacestodock
  gnome-shell-extensions gnome-sushi gnupg-agent gnupg2 graphviz
  gsettings-desktop-schemas gstreamer1.0-libav iceweasel initramfs-tools
  iptables isc-dhcp-client king-phisher libasan2 libasound2-plugins libatomic1
  libcamel-1.2-54 libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libecal-1.2-19 libedata-cal-1.2-28
  libenchant1c2a libgcc-5-dev libgcc1 libgdm1 libgfortran3 libgl1-mesa-dri
  libgomp1 libgs9 libgs9-common libgvc6 libimobiledevice6 libinput10 libitm1
  libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 liblognorm2 liblsan0
  libmm-glib0 libmpx0 libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libobjc-5-dev libobjc4
  libpackage-deprecationmanager-perl libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0
  libpulsedsp libpython3-stdlib libqmi-proxy libqt5gui5 libquadmath0
  libradare2-0.9.9 libradare2-dev libstdc++-5-dev libstdc++6
  libtotem-plparser18 libtotem0 libtsan0 libubsan0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libxatracker2 linux-image-amd64 mesa-vdpau-drivers
  metasploit-framework mitmproxy modemmanager mutter mutter-common netsniff-ng
  network-manager-gnome ntfs-3g pack postgresql-9.5 postgresql-contrib-9.5
  pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-x11
  pulseaudio-utils python-dbus-dev python-netlib python-pefile
  python-pycryptopp python-pyregfi python-service-identity python3 python3-apt
  python3-brlapi python3-cairo python3-cups python3-dbus python3-gi
  python3-gi-cairo python3-minimal python3-smbc radare2 reglookup rsyslog ruby
  ruby-atomic ruby-dataobjects-mysql ruby-dataobjects-postgres
  ruby-dataobjects-sqlite3 ruby-dev ruby-eventmachine ruby-ffi ruby-http
  ruby-http-parser.rb ruby-json ruby-msgpack ruby-nokogiri ruby-oj
  ruby-rubydns ruby-sqlite3 ruby-therubyracer ruby-unf-ext ruby-yajl
  termineter testdisk thin totem totem-common tzdata vim vim-common vim-gtk
  vim-gui-common vim-runtime vim-tiny vlc vlc-nox xserver-xorg-input-all
  xserver-xorg-video-all xsser
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 165 not upgraded.
```

Comment: It is just informing you that these files have no use on your system. So you can remove them by running `apt auto remove` command if you like.

Answer (score 1):

They are meant to be packages no longer used any more, it is likely that packages have been installed which replace them, but if you don't want to remove them, just don't run `sudo apt-get autoremove` and bare with the message (if you don't run that command the upgrade won't remove those packages). Also, it is inadvisable to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` as that does not upgrade the important stuff which needs upgrading (as you can see from the message), so I highly advise that you run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` instead.

```
   dist-upgrade
       dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
       also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
       of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
       it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
       expense of less important ones if necessary. The dist-upgrade
       command may therefore remove some packages. The
       /etc/apt/sources.list file contains a list of locations from which
       to retrieve desired package files. See also apt_preferences(5) for
       a mechanism for overriding the general settings for individual
       packages.
```

(The above is from the `apt-get` manpage: `man apt-get`.)